# Mongo DB updates with aggregation pipeline with Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, aggregation-framework

Mongo DB allows to use aggregation pipelines in the update operations. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/

I would like to achieve this, using Kotlin/Java driver. I current situation I would like to change the date property in the document into string. Not sure if it's possible to do, I don't see any documentation for that in the Java Driver doc (ofc the code below doesn't work, this is just a draft):

```
    fun changeProductLaunchDate(db: MongoDatabase) {
    db.getCollection("productLine").updateMany(
        and(
            ne("products", null),
            or(
                type("products.launchDate", BsonType.DATE_TIME),
            )
        ),
            set(
                "products.launchDate", Document(
                    "$dateToString", mapOf(
                        "date" to "\$products.launchDate",
                        "format" to "%d-%m-%Y",
                        "timezone" to "GMT",
                        "onNull" to null
                    )
                )
            )
    )
}
```

Did anybody had an experience with that? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
        db.getCollection("groupProductLine").updateMany(
        and(
            ne("products", null),
            or(
                type("products.launchDate", BsonType.DATE_TIME)
            )
        ),
        listOf(
            set(
                "products.lLaunchDate",
                Document(
                    "\$dateToString",
                    Document("date", "\$products.launchDate")
                        .append("format", "%d-%m-%Y")
                        .append("timezone", "+02:00")
                        .append("onNull", null)
                )
            )
        )
    )
```